# Reported height of DIV is changing upon refresh with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of Javascript calculating the position of a certain DIV.  This JS is within some other JS and jQuery within a document.ready.

Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="outer-box">
    <table id="text-preview">
        <tr>
            <td>
                TESTING THIS.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('text-preview');
var positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect();

var outerelement = document.getElementById('outer-box');
var outerpositionInfo = outerelement.getBoundingClientRect();
var outerheight = outerpositionInfo.height;
var textpreviewheight = positionInfo.height;
```

What I am finding is, on first load, the var textpreviewheight is 94.

When I refresh the page it is 62.

If I clear cookies it goes back to 94.

The ACTUAL height is 62.

Maybe I am just not fully understanding how cookies work with JS, but is there something specific I should be looking for in this case?

Comment: The provided code has nothing to do with cookies. As a matter of fact the height of both is 18 under default browser. You must have css and other code that is changing things. You sure this is all the corresponding code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(window).on('load')` instead of `$(document).ready()` when you need to read UI component values. That way, you ensure the entire window UI is fully loaded (not only ready) before reading the component value.

I think the final value of 62 is the actual height after the window is fully loaded. 94 is height just immediately after the DOM is ready. The discrepancies may be as a result of interaction with other UI components before a full load of the page.

```html
<body>
<div id="outer-box">
    <table id="text-preview">
        <tr>
            <td>
                TESTING THIS.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('text-preview');
        var positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    
        var outerelement = document.getElementById('outer-box');
        var outerpositionInfo = outerelement.getBoundingClientRect();
        var outerheight = outerpositionInfo.height;
        var textpreviewheight = positionInfo.height;
        console.log(textpreviewheight);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah I think you are probably right.  I am going to have to rework some of the other code to do this, but that seems to be what I have to do.  Let me try to work that out real quick.

Comment: this is just my opinion. Let me know if it works. thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you are right actually.  I thought that might be it, but it just didn't make sense.  Still baffled why the refresh makes a difference.  Doing some final testing and I will upvote.

Comment: yeah that seems to be it.  Thanks much!